# Creating a "data-dump" table procedurally?

Tags: tables, pgfplots, statistics

I have a ~50 sample dataset I'd like to put into a table. Because there's only one variable to display, a single column chart looks ridiculous and wastes a lot of space. Is there a way I can get it to fill the page with data (i.e., wrap the data horizontally and vertically)? I'm imagining something like this image, with the header row taking up the full width, and the data cells in between. I tried using `pgfplotstable`, but I couldn't really wrap my head around it.

[image: Table with a full-width header row and data cells evenly spaced in between]

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! Please also post a **minimum working example (MWE)** you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: You can just figure out how to do the task "manually", then write a program in other programming language (e.g. Python, Lua etc.) to write the TeX code.

Comment: Please add an example representative of your dataset, including type of data to list, separation char, etc. Or do you want to transform a LaTeX table already built of 1x50 to a nxm new table?